# Problem with file reading, stuck without output when run

Tags: pascal

I'm trying to do a program that reads numbers from a file, outputs them into a vector and then writes them. The code compiles nicely, but when run, it gets stuck with just a prompt without delivering any output.

Program LectorDeEnteros;

```
type 
    Arreglo = array [1..30] of integer;
var  
    //Arch:text;
    Prom:byte;
    i:integer;
    ArregloA:Arreglo;

Procedure CargadorVectorialdeArchivo (var ArregloA:Arreglo);
    var 
        Arch:text;
        i:integer;

Begin 
    assign (Arch,'Numeros.txt');
    reset (Arch);   

    i := 1;
    while not eof(Arch) do
        Write(Arch);Read(ArregloA[i]);
        i := i + 1;
End;

Begin 

    CargadorVectorialdeArchivo(ArregloA);


    for i := 1 to 14 do 
        WriteLn(ArregloA[i]:3);

End.
```

As i said, there are no error messages, just the prompt and no output. I have to CTRL-Z to get it out of this "loop". The expected output would be the numbers of the array, one on each line.

Comment: 1) You can't test for `Eof(Arch)` with the file open for output, because you're writing to the file. 2) You don't write any content with `Write(Arch)`, because you've not provided any data to write. 3) You're not putting any content into `ArregloA` before you pass it in to the functino. 4) You don't `Read()` an array as you are doing in your code. You need to back up and start over. Think about the steps you would need to take to get several values into an array (a list of items) and then write that list out to a file.

Comment: Additionally your i+1 is outside the while loop. You have to use proper indentation to notice such errors.

Comment: Thanks to both of you! And also, what would account as proper indentation?

Comment: That statement (i:=i+1) should be indented at the same level with the "while", because there is no enclosing begin/end. Then you'd notice the mistake.

Comment: @KenWhite, i fixed the write and read thing. I had them interchanged in my head, and also fixed the writing on the array but now it's outputing some random string of numbers (which are not on the file) and then zeroes, on per line.

Comment: Unfortunately SO is not an incremental-debugging or code-writing service. Please see [help] for how to use this site.

Comment: That means that you have not corrected the issue of actually putting values into the array. The *random string of numbers* are random memory contents caused by using variables that have not been initialized. I can't tell you what's wrong with your current version of your code after you changed it, because I can't see your screen from here. I'd suggest you learn to use the debugger to step through the code to see what's happening.

Comment: Is "Numeros.txt" the file with the numbers you want to read? The Read(ArregloA[i]) statement in your program, is not going to read from that file. It is going to try and read from the standard input (which is usually the keyboard). So your program is waiting for you to type the numbers you want to read. Take another look at how the read statement works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rewrite the procedure as this:

```
Procedure CargadorVectorialdeArchivo (var ArregloA:Arreglo);
    var 
        Arch:text;
        i:integer;

Begin 
    assign (Arch,'Numeros.txt');
    reset (Arch);   

    i := 1;
    while not eof(Arch) do
       begin 
        Read(Arch,ArregloA[i]); 
        i := i + 1;
       end;
End;
```

Putting `Arch` in front of the file tells the compiler that you want to read the contents from that file, not from the keyboard.